# Master/Detail relationship in one query

Tags: mysql

I am not frequent SQL coder, I use it only for a simple tasks. I want to find a solution for a probably simple problem.

I have two tables:

```
Master_tbl [fields: ID, Plant, Detail_Group_ID]
```

and

```
Detail_tbl [fields: ID, Group_ID, Plant]
```

With such example data:

`Master_tbl`:

```
ID  Plant   Detail_Group_ID

1    Tree       1

2    Flower     2
```

`Detail_tbl`:

```
ID  Group_ID    Plant

1   1            Oak

2   1            Apple

3   1            Spruce

4   1            Maple

5   2            Tulip

6   2            Rose

7   2            Violet

8   2            Orchid
```

I want to make SQL statement to put two tables in one (in *master/detail* way):

The result table should display data in Treeview like fashion, where master fields are like parent nodes and detail fields like child nodes (see outcome below). I am not really sure, if this could be mastered via SQL...

> **Plant**
>
> ***Tree***
>
> Oak
>
> Apple
>
> Spruce
>
> Maple
>
> ***Flower***
>
> Tulip
>
> Rose
>
> Violet
>
> Orchid

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Master_tbl.Plant as `Group`, Detail_tbl.Plant as Plant FROM Master_tbl
JOIN Detail_tbl on Master_tbl.Detail_Group_ID=Detail_tbl.Group_ID
```

That will give you output like:

```
Group   Plant
Tree    Oak
Tree    Apple
Tree    Spruce
Tree    Maple
Flower  Tulip
Flower  Rose
Flower  Violet
Flower  Orchid
```

---

Here's another option:

```
SELECT Master_tbl.Plant as `Group`, group_concat(Detail_tbl.Plant) as Plants 
FROM Master_tbl JOIN Detail_tbl on Master_tbl.Detail_Group_ID=Detail_tbl.Group_ID
group by `Group`;
```

The output is:

```
+--------+--------------------------+
| Group  | Plants                   |
+--------+--------------------------+
| Flower | Tulip,Rose,Violet,Orchid |
| Tree   | Oak,Apple,Spruce,Maple   |
+--------+--------------------------+
```

It's not necessarily the tree you wanted, but I think it's as close as you can get.  In everything I could find, I couldn't find a way to get the tree output in one column like you posted.  However, with these two queries, you can very easily parse the results based on the group.

Comment: Yes, thanx, but can you make SQL to make table look like my template? 
(I edited my question to clarify my intention)

Comment: Thanx very much for your answer... There was a little hope in UNION statement together with something else... but I see, I have to parse the result table... appreciate your effort... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select lista.* from
(
SELECT Master_tbl.ID MasterID, 0 DetailID, Master_tbl.Plant FROM Master_tbl

UNION

SELECT Master_tbl.ID MasterID, Detail_tbl.Group_ID DetailID, Detail_tbl.Plant FROM Master_tbl
JOIN Detail_tbl on Master_tbl.Detail_Group_ID=Detail_tbl.Group_ID
) lista
order by MasterID, DetailID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT d.Plant FROM Detail_tbl d INNER JOIN Master_tbl m ON
d.Group_ID = m.Detail_Group_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like a JOIN ?

```
SELECT Master_tbl.ID as Master_ID, Master_tbl.Plant as Master_Plant, Detail_tbl.* FROM Master_tbl INNER JOIN Detail_tbl ON Master_tbl.Detail_Group_ID = Detail_tbl.Group_ID
```